# Vue2 multiple v-for scenario

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

roleList Object will have the following array:

```
{
  groupName: Client Login,
  roleID: 1,
  roleName: View Own Profile,
  roleChecked: false
},
{
  groupName: Client Login,
  roleID: 1,
  roleName: View Own Invoices,
  roleChecked: false
},
{
  groupName: Client Management,
  roleID: 1,
  roleName: View Clients,
  roleChecked: true
},
{
  groupName: Client Management,
  roleID: 1,
  roleName: Create Client,
  roleChecked: false
}
```

I want the groupName to be the header of a section with a list of roles under that group name. groupName and roleName are checkboxes therefore if a groupName is clicked, all corresponding roles will also be checked. If one of the roles are unchecked the groupName will also uncheck. the roleChecked is just a default checkbox (clicked or not clicked).

So the Example would be:

**[ ] Client Login**

[ ] View Own Profile

[ ] View Own Invoices

I am trying to work out how to structure the v-for and the behaviour of the checkbox using Vue2. I may add roles and groups later therefore needing this to be dynamic.

Comment: Would anyone have any interest in providing something that I could work with to resolve this issue?

Comment: Reading into some posts, I assume I would need to use a computed property to group the headers and style the overall result?

Comment: Solution made within another forum: [https://forum.vuejs.org/t/group-array-using-computed-property/38355](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/group-array-using-computed-property/38355)